# How can I efficiently identify that 2 URLs will return different content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, url, web, web-crawler

I want to check if 2 URLs are different or same, i.e. whether the HTTP response is going to be same. Let's say I have a URL `http://www.example.com/some/path?q=abc&time=12334`. I then create a base URL from this `http://www.example.com/some/path`. Now I want to check whether these URLs point to the same piece of content, or to different sets. In general they will be same, but they are going to be different if the response is based on query parameters. Here is an example:

`https://www.google.co.in/search?q=techcrunch&source=lnms&tbm=isch` and `https://www.google.co.in/search` are different URLs. The obvious way is to do a GET request and compare the response (or may be page titles, which would practically work), or maintain a cached list of such websites (and keep updating - error prone and more reactive in nature).

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I tried comparing "Content Length" of the 2 requests by doing a HEAD request, but a lot of them don't necessarily return it. Are there any more possible approaches to this problem?

Comment: The only way to tell if two requests return different information is to make two requests. Note that the content length could be identical but the content 100% different.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was looking for a more practical and efficient solution with some margin for error. But may be there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

Just something simple you can try.

```
require 'net/http'
first = Net::HTTP.get('google.com', '/')
second = Net::HTTP.get('twitter.com', '/')
first == second #=> false
```

Comment: This won't work, as there are identifiers (CSRF tokens, etc.) in web pages which change on each load. Though a variation of this might work, as I mentioned in the question - like comparing titles, etc. But I am looking for a more efficient approach if that's possible.